# What version should I download for this Linux OS?

Tags: linux, compatibility, linux-distributions, gnu, gnu-parallel

I would like to install [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) on a computer cluster. I see there are several versions of GNU-parallel one can download (see above link under “Downloading GNU Parallel”). I suppose the versions of main interest to me are:

- Arch Linux
- Alpine Linux
- Alt Linux
- Mageia Linux
- CERN CENTOS

I `ssh` to the cluster and did

```
$ uname -s
Linux
$ uname -m
x86_64
$ uname -r
2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64
$ lsb_release -si
CentOS
```

What version of GNU Parallel would be compatible with the cluster's OS?

Comment: I posted this question on SO before and got close votes so I moved it here where I get a `primarily-opinion based` close vote. I can trust you it is correct but I would love some explanation to understand why. I am trying to understand what version would be compatible with a given OS. Why is this opinion-based? If I fail to understand which version I should use, I will just try them all until I find one that seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see there are several versions of GNU-parallel one can download (see
>   above link under “Downloading GNU Parallel”).

The premise of your question is flawed: What you are describing as “versions” are simply packages customized for each different Linux OS out there to properly install it within that OS’s file system structure. Core coding for any package available on different systems/OS’s should not be different at all.

All the package availability means—for example—is that if you run `yum install` (RedHat/CentOS) or `apt-get install` (Debian/Ubuntu)—a package is readily available for you to just do that: Install the package with one command instead of doing it from source. This is not unique to GNU Parallel but is basically the way every software available via a package installer works.